# How to share a ASP.NET SQLDataSource acorss different page and project?

Tags: c#

I know you can share control easily with master page.  But what if I need to share my control with pages under different master or even in different project?  Specifically I have SQLDataSource which I am hoping to not have to duplicate across my entire solution for each masterPage that I have.

Do I need to have nested master page to achieve this?

A possible solution is to put my SQL DataSource control in a seperate page.  And have each different master page always load that page into a ContentPlaceHolder.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is more flexible to use `IEnumerable<TEntity>` instead of `List<TEntity>` for return type.

Comment: Yes. I was just using it as an example for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `Data Access Layer (DAL)`. Therefore you can share data calls across all of your pages instead of using inflexible `SqlDataSource` controls.

The following example *is very basic*. I used the `Entity Framework` to access the database and `Web Forms`.

```
public class DataAccess
{

   public List<Record> GetAllRecordsByUserName(string credentials)
   {
      List<Record> recordList;
      using (CustomEntities context = new CustomEntities())
      {

        IQueryable<Section> recordQuery = from records in context.Records
                                              where records.UserName == credentials
                                              select records; 
        recordList = recordQuery.ToList<Record>();
      }
      return recordList;
   }

}
```

---

**In your code behind**

```
DataAccess access = new DataAccess();
List<Record> records = access.GetAllRecordsByUserName("user.name");
DropDownList1.DataSource = records;
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

---

**Tutorial**

There is a great tutorial on `asp.net` about creating a `DAL`. I strongly recommend you go though it. It is much more through and educational than my little code snippets.

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/introduction/creating-a-data-access-layer-cs

Comment: Ok I get Data Layer and that whole shibam, which I am using by the way.  The problem is that I am using SQL Data Source, which is a ASP.NET entity, not a C# entity.  So it doesn't go in a C# object.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're getting at. My point was to move away from using SqlDataSource because it causes the problem you currently have. It is really just a "band-aid" sort of approach to displaying data on your page.

Comment: Yea, I guess what I am trying to ask is if I can keep on using this "band-aid" solution.  I will convert away to your solution if I need to, but if possible I would prefer to just keep the current SqlDataSource.

Comment: I completely understand not wanting to mess with that is currently working. You could store your SqlDataSource into a User Control and use that across your pages if you want to keep using that solution.

Answer (score 0):

At the end, I made nested Master and put my SQL Data Source at the top most level, so each sub-master can access it.